# Can not save object to MySQL DB using Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I've got ENTITY **Country** with all getters and setters + Constructor with no args. Getters and setter are all written by IDEA, not Lombok.

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Country {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String code;
private String capital;
private String description;
private String nationality;
private String continent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="country")
private List<State> states;


public Country() {
}`
```

Here goes **CountryRepository**:

```
 @Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {}
```

Here goes `CountryService`:

```
@Service
public class CountryService {
    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    public List<Country> getListOfCountries() {
        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewCountry(Country country) {
        countryRepository.save(country);
    }
}
```

and **CountryController**:

```
@Controller
public class CountryController {
    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @GetMapping("/countries")
    private String getListOfCountries(Model model) {
        List<Country> listOfCountries = countryService.getListOfCountries();
        model.addAttribute("countries", listOfCountries);
        return "countries";
    }

    @PostMapping("/countries/addNew")
    private String addNewCountry(@RequestParam String code,
                                 @RequestParam String capital,
                                 @RequestParam String description,
                                 @RequestParam String nationality,
                                 @RequestParam String continent) {
        Country country = new Country();
        country.setCode(code);
        country.setCapital(capital);
        country.setDescription(description);
        country.setNationality(nationality);
        country.setContinent(continent);
        countryService.addNewCountry(country);
        return "redirect:/countries";
    }
}
```

and here is the **form** that's supposed to take input, but unfortunately nothing happens(

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <form th:action="@{/countries/addNew}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Code:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" name="code">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name1" class="col-form-label">Capital:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name1" name="capital">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name2" class="col-form-label">Description:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name2" name="description">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name3" class="col-form-label">Nationality:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name3" name="nationality">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name4" class="col-form-label">Continent:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name4" name="continent">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

If I add data manually to the DB everything works fine, but when using this form nothing happens. At the same time I didn't get to errors or whatever. Server runs OK. Instead of JPARepository I tried using CRUDRepository. Also doblechecked the names of the form so they have the same values as **Country** fields. Realy lost here...

Comment: I see `@Table` is missing. Maybe add it? In your position, I will try to run some `@DataJpaTest` to check if db url/credentials/mapping are good or not; then maybe some integration tests before doing HTML; then E2E tests(like you do, providing data from HTML forms to backend, then database, then return back to front end). Take small steps.

Comment: And I will try to remove all relationships mapping first(no FK, no OneToMany, etc.), to make sure first I can find a table, I can CRUD in that table, then adding FKs, and more.

Comment: Hi, in addition to what @WesternGun mentioned above, try to **debug** your `CountryController`, place a breakpoint in `countryService.addNewCountry(country);` and inspect if everything there is as it should be. Then proceed to `CountryService#addNewCountry` method and also debug there.

Comment: Also just noticed `private String addNewCountry(...)`. Your controller's method is **private**? Try changing it to public

Comment: If possible could you please add error logs. It will be vary helpful.